# Trying to redirect a user based on his level

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel 5.3

I have this middleware(*roles*) to check if a user is a Admin (by checking a column called *isAdmin* in user table).

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        $next($request);

        dd(Auth::user()); //returns null

        if ($request->user()->isAdmin()){
            return redirect('admin-home');
        }

        return redirect('user-home');
    }
```

The problem is: `Auth::user()` return null always so i cant test if a user is admin or not. Im using laravel default auth system, so a assigned the middleware to the action like this:

```
LoginController extends Controler{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('roles', ['only' => 'login']);
    }
```

}

Since i've done `next($request);` i thought that `Auth::user()` would return the current then i would redirect him to correct view according his level. How can i fix it to check de level of a user and redirect him? I know that it is kinda massy and probably exists many better ways to achieve it but i really want to implement this before to try other approach.

Comment: Is your route in the `web` middleware? Run `php artisan route:list` if you are not sure.

Comment: Yes, it is in web middleware

Comment: any luck? this seems interesting